# How do i make my bot reply with a bigger version of the emoji on discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a command that makes the bot respond to your message (!big :emoji:) with that emoji just bigger. Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE: Is there a way to do this with all emojis and not just custom ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a command with an argument specified as `discord.Emoji` or `str`

- `discord.Emoji` is for custom emojis
- `str` for default unicode emojis checked against `UNICODE_EMOJI`

Here is a example using [`Emoji.url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji.url) and `UNICODE_EMOJI`

```py
# from typing import Union
# from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

@bot.command()
async def big(ctx, emoji: Union[discord.Emoji, str] = None):
    # custom emoji
    if isinstance(emoji, discord.Emoji):
        await ctx.send(emoji.url)
    # default emoji
    elif isinstance(emoji, str) and emoji in UNICODE_EMOJI:
        await ctx.send(emoji)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not a valid emoji")
```

Answer (score 1):

You an simply get the url of custom discord emojis, or use the twitter emoji api to get images of the default emotes

```py
@bot.command()
async def emoji(ctx, emoji: Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji, str]):
    """Post a large size emojis in chat."""
    if not isinstance(emoji, str):  # if it is a custom discord emoji
        d_emoji = cast(discord.Emoji, emoji)
        ext = "gif" if d_emoji.animated else "png"
        url = d_emoji.url
        filename = f"{d_emoji.name}.{ext}"
    else:  # use the twitter emoji api
        try:
            cdn_fmt = "https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/72x72/{codepoint:x}.png"
            url = cdn_fmt.format(codepoint=ord(str(emoji)))
            filename = "emoji.png"
        except TypeError:
            return await ctx.send("That doesn't appear to be a valid emoji")
    try:  # read it with BytesIO so you dont need to save the image
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                image = os.BytesIO(await resp.read())
    except Exception:
        return await ctx.send("That doesn't appear to be a valid emoji")
    file = discord.File(image, filename=filename)
    await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Comment: You could also just send the url by its own, with the "Embed links"-permissions it will also be shown as an image