# Discord.py/rewrite - enlarge emojis command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I made an enlarge command that enlarges custom emojis in servers, and it works but I want to get it to where it does default emojis as well. I don’t know how to do default ones, so can someone help?

Here’s the current code:

```
   @commands.command()
    async def enlarge(self, ctx, emoji: typing.Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji, str]):
      if type(emoji) is str:
        return await ctx.reply('Please enter an emoji to enlarge!')
      else:
        await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

Comment: What do you mean default emojis? Like the standard set of emojis you'd see on an iPhone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i make my bot reply with a bigger version of the emoji on discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569573/how-do-i-make-my-bot-reply-with-a-bigger-version-of-the-emoji-on-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

The default discord emoji are just unicode characters.
This is also the reason why custom emoji return an [Emoji-Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Emoji), while default ones only return a string or single character. What you want to do is convert the unicode emoji characters to an image that represents them.

For this, you need some source of those images.
As described in [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/scragly/b8d20aece2d058c8c601b44a689a47a0), discord uses [Twemoji](https://twemoji.twitter.com/) as their default emoji source.
In the [Twemoji-Github](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji), they mention [MaxCDN](https://www.stackpath.com/maxcdn) as their CDN supporter.
While this is meant to primarily address Javascript-Developers who want to use the Twemoji-scripts on their websites, it also provides the emoji icons.

It is possible to fetch those icons via
`https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/EMOJI_SIZE/EMOJI_ID.png` In this url, you need to replace `EMOJI_SIZE` by the image size (`72x72` is currently the only one available, but it should fit your needs quite well).

You also need to determine your emojis “id”/[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) codepoint (denoted by `EMOJI_ID` in above link), an integer in hexadecimal notation which represents your emoji character.
If `emoji` stores your character, you can obtain this integer using

```py
emoji_id = ord(emoji)
```

Putting it all together, your command could look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def enlarge(ctx, emoji: typing.Union[discord.Emoji, discord.PartialEmoji, str]):
    if type(emoji) is str:
        emoji_id = ord(emoji[0]) # Emoji is a string, we will use the first character
        await ctx.send(f'https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/72x72/{emoji_id:x}.png')
    else:
        await ctx.send(emoji.url)
```

Note that I use Python's [f-Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for formatting which is supported since Python 3.6.
If you are running an older version, you have to use another way of formatting.
Keep in mind that you will need the hexadecimal representation in your url.

If you don't want to use MaxCDN to serve the images, you could also download them at [the Twemoji Github](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/tree/master/assets) and store them locally.

Inside discord, it is also possible to right-click an emoji and get a discordcdn-link, but I wasn't able to construct those links from a given emoji.
Maybe someone else knows how to do this in order to avoid external services like MaxCDN.

Comment: beautiful answer.