# Enlarge default emojis discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Is there a way to send enlarged default emojis with discord.py?

I found a way to do this with custom emojis but not with the default ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i make my bot reply with a bigger version of the emoji on discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569573/how-do-i-make-my-bot-reply-with-a-bigger-version-of-the-emoji-on-discord-py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have seen my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68571066/13975447) for custom emojis, I edited it to include default emojis also.

Here is an edited version with default emojis. `UNICODE_EMOJI` is a set of emojis built-in Python you can check in it to validate that the string input is a valid emoji.

```py
# from typing import Union
# from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

@bot.command()
async def big(ctx, emoji: Union[discord.Emoji, str] = None):
    # custom emoji
    if isinstance(emoji, discord.Emoji):
        await ctx.send(emoji.url)
    # default emoji
    elif isinstance(emoji, str) and emoji in UNICODE_EMOJI:
        await ctx.send(emoji)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not a valid emoji")
```

Answer (score -2):

I`m not sure if I understand your question right but if i do you can just do:

```
await message.channel.send("")#for this emojie just press windows+dot
```